# How to use hclust() in R when dataset has NA values

Tags: r, na, hclust

How can I use `hclust()` in R when the dataset I am using has NA values? This is the function I have set up:

```
data2 = apply(data,2, as.numeric)
data2.hclust = hclust(data2, method='median')
```

When I attempt this I receive this error message:

```
Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Is there anyway to use the `hclust()` function even with NA values?

Comment: You don't call `hclust` directly on your data, you call it on a `dist` object, ie. `hclust(dist(data2))`.

Comment: Also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343398/how-to-use-hclust-as-function-call-in-r